# Partition Reset in Redmi 1S

Tags: internal-storage, partitions, redmi-1s

Running custom Rom on my Redmi 1s, I changed to stock MIUI 9 Rom. Then, I installed latest MIUI 8.2 on it and rooted. I cannot boot into TWRP, so I installed ClockWorkMod, and tried to install custom ROM and failed. I thought it was due to file type issue, and I partitioned Internal storage(followed steps in CWM). Now, the internal storage got reduced to 4.6 GB.

Tasks performed:

1. Installed stock MIUI 5 using fastboot mode. Then, installed latest MIUI 8.2, shows 4 GB in ES file explorer.
2. Changed partition table to default mode, using adb shell with parted.
3. Then, I have increased /system partition to 2GB using parted.
4. Now running, custom Rom with aroma Gapps.(This custom rom was backed up a month before partitioning internal storage, Restoring this also doesn't solved the issue).

Now, in settings it shows 4.31 gb of 7.28 GB used. Es file explorer shows used 1.65 Gb out of 4.62 GB. Also, I cannot access Internal storage in TWRP recovery.

How to reset it back to 8GB?

Comment: Have you ever tried this one?
https://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-1s/general/tut-repartition-redmi-1s-to-increase-t3506904 Please check the PS section.

Comment: This one I have used. But, the problem is not about /system partition. Its about internal storage. Device has 8GB storage, but now I have access only to 4.3 GB which is half the size. Now the device is not with me.